# In Rails, how do I customise the link_to_add layout when using simple_nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, simple-form

I'm trying to work out if there is a way to customise the HTML inserted by link_to_add when using the nested_form/simple_form gems in Rails 3.

At the moment it generates a div, but I would like it to generate a table row.

I have seen an example of using the Cocoon gem but using nested_form would be my preference.

The current code is pretty straight forward:

```
table.table.table-striped
  tr 
    th Name
    th Notes
    th $ Value
    th
    = f.simple_fields_for :client_contracted_rates do |ccr|
      tr
        td = ccr.text_field :name, :class => "span2"
        td = ccr.text_field :notes, :class => "span2"
        td = ccr.text_field :value, :class => "span1"
        td = ccr.link_to_remove "x", :class => "btn btn-mini btn-danger"

= f.link_to_add "+ Add Contracted Rate", :client_contracted_rates, :class => "btn pull-right"
```

I'm hoping to generate a table row, or at least something different to the div and input defaults.

Cheers,

Jono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not using the **f.link_to_add** and just used a **= link_to** approach instead.

This allowed me to wrap the **= link_to** inside the table row as needed.